# Use of "space" and "room"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

> Example 1: Is there any **room** for me to sit?.
>
> Example 2: I have got to make some **space** for Mark's things.

I am a little confused where to use **space** and **room**. I always make an error when using these words.

Comment: I usually go by my intuition, and I think I can't spell the rules out (keep in mind that I'm a non-native speaker); however, you might find my intuition useful. Both *space* and *room* can be used for an empty area. The subtle difference, as far as I can tell, is that *room* usually implies "enough" space. The contrast can be observed in common expressions: "clear a space", but "make room".

Comment: Just to add *'[room and space](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/room%20and%20space)'* is also possible! :)

Comment: "Room and space" appears to be some kind of nautical jargon.  It's a mistake to link to it here.

Comment: I agree with Damkerng's intuition.  I also tend to think of _room_ being used for activities while _space_ is used for static purposes.  For example, if I make room for my car in my garage I think of the car plus all the activities associated with it like getting in and out, working on it, walking around it.  If I just make space for the car then I'm just making sure the car can fit.  Also when I say I want to do an action I use "room".  I need room to stand, room to grow, room to run around, and room to eat.

Answer (score 2):

To me, *room* means *a space with specific dimensions*. As Damkerng T. noted, it implies that the space is sufficient for a certain purpose.

> Make room for me!

Means: *Clear a space of sufficient dimensions for me to sit on.*

> Go mark down a 5" by 5" space in our yard, please.

In this example *space* is being used to refer to a space of geometrical dimensions. 
You could not use the word *room* here, which is defined as *an extent of space occupied by or sufficient or available for something*.

To further clarify, take a look at the following example including both the terms *space* and *room*:

> Please mark down a space^ in our yard with room^^ for our car.

^ *no dimensions specified, so far it could mean a space of **any** size*

^^ *room for our car* clarifies that the the space must be big enough to fit an object of size X.

Also, you can use the word "spot" (*a particular place, area, or part*) to refer to a space that's of sufficient dimensions for something.

> I need a spot for my car.

*Spot* implies that the space needs to be big enough to fit a certain object as well.